# merge two data.frame substituting column with same names in r

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I am struggling to merge two data.frame with columns with the same name but different values. I want to replace with a single command the column in df1 with the columns in df2 that have the same names keeping the other columns of df 1 untouched.

```
DF1

    a   b   c   d    e  
1   3   1   2   8    1
2   4   2   1   10   2
3   12  1   1   13   2
4   12  2   2   9    2


DF2

    b   c   e  
1   2   1   2 
2   1   2   1 
3   2   2   1
4   1   1   1
```

The results should look like this

```
        a   b   c   d    e  
    1   3   2   1   8    2
    2   4   1   2   10   1
    3   12  2   2   13   1
    4   12  1   1   9    1
```

Note that i don't have an ID in the dataframe.

I've tried with may different packages in r. The best result that I've obtained is the join package in the dplyr

```
df1 <- left_join(df1, df2, copy = TRUE)
```

But the values of the target columns are equal of df1 and not to df2

USING df2 first results in the correct values but if fills the non-target columns (a and d) with NAs

```
df1 <- left_join(df2, df1, copy = TRUE)
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

EDIT:

ANSWER provided is

```
dat1[names(dat2)] <- dat2
```

Comment: Probably as simple as `dat1[names(dat2)] <- dat2` as long as each has the same number of rows and the names of dat2 are in dat1.

Comment: amazingly simple,  that was exactly was i was looking for! Thanks